# In ansible how can we include all task files in a directory

Tags: python, ansible

I have a directory with task files and I want to loop through those task files and include them in my playbook. How can I do this?

I tried the following but that does not seem to work,

```
- include: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: export.stdout_lines
```

This gives me an error,

```
ERROR: [DEPRECATED]: include + with_items is a removed deprecated feature.  Please update your playbooks.
```

I looked at other posts on stackoverflow for that particular error and the workaround but it does not seem to be relevant to my problem.

I am using ansible 1.9.4.

Answer (score 8):

There is no workaround in the version of Ansible you use. In your version, includes are resolved before any task is executed etc. Therefore you can not depend on variables or results from other tasks to include files.

If you need this, you need to update Ansible to version 2.x where this feature was re-introduced. This feature was also working in an earlier version, but only by accident and had uncontrollable side effects and therefore was removed.

With Ansible 2 you ideally then would use [with_fileglob](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#id4):

```
- include_tasks: "{{ item }}"
  with_fileglob:
    - path/to/your/tasks/*.yml
```